# No regex match in perl with large files

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following simple script:

```
my $filename = './log_file';
my $file; 
open(FILE, "$filename") or die "Cant open $filename\n"; 
local $/ = undef; 
$file = <FILE>; 
close(FILE); 
my $regexp = 'Something\n';
print "OK\n" if ($file =~ m{$regexp}msg);
```

The content of log_file is:

```
Something
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
Nothing
.
.
.
```

When the size of log_file 2GB then the script prints OK.
But when the size of it is 2.1GB or more then it doesn't print OK.
Anybody knows why? And how to solve this problem? I don't want to split the file because my regular expression is multiline

Comment: What is your actual regex?

Comment: Is this a 32 bit Perl?  What OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your perl may not be compiled with `USE_LARGE_FILES` enabled which would limit your file sizes to 2 gigs.  You can verify this with the following command like check:

```
$perl -V:uselargefiles
uselargefiles='define';
```

As dethorpe has already suggested, no matter what, it would probably be wise to modify your script to process things line by line, or if you are testing across multiple lines, then using a buffer.

Here is an example of how you could use a buffer of 5 lines to test a multiline regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @buffer;

while (<DATA>) {
    push @buffer, $_;

    if (@buffer == 5 || eof) {
        my $buffer = join '', @buffer;
        while ($buffer =~ m{([a-z]+)\n(\d+)}g) {
            # Truncate buffer for match found
            @buffer = substr $buffer, pos $buffer;

            print "$1\n";
        }

        shift @buffer;
    }
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
abc
123
10
def
456 ghi
789
13
14
15
16
```

Outputs

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 4):

Your reading the whole file into memory when you load it into your variable. This might cause you to run out of memory when its above 2GB (depending on system resources). Also depending on your OS may be hitting issues with largefile handling under the hood (especially on 32bit systems) , checkout "man largefile" on unix, this kicks in at 2GB.

Given the size it would probably be best to read line or chunk at a time in a loop rather than slurp the whole thing. Maybe handle the multiline match by using a rolling 2 (or more) line window on the file as you read it in.

Comment: I get out of memory with 32 bit per, but with 64 bit perl there is no out of memory and there is no match also